# How to return Typeahead results as Hyperlink

Tags: javascript, typeahead, fuzzy-search, fuzzy-logic

I need to build a FuzzySearch for my website. I have used the below from git.

```
https://github.com/jeancroy/FuzzySearch
```

As I need the return elements as hyperlink, I added this code.

```
    return [
        '<a class="srd" href=', fuzzyhound.highlight(suggestion.author,"author") , '>' , '</a>',
    ].join("");
```

This code shows the results as hyperlink, but doesnt work. Can someone help me make it work.

Comment: May be you should use double quotes `"` around `href`

Answer (score 0):

The  tag is not closed properly.Lack of `>`